# PHP Ajax function is not working in the Win 2003 machin

Tags: php, ajax

I have written a ajax function in javascript (for php). It's working fine in WIN-XP machine but it's not working in Win-2003.

For onclick event I am calling the `fun_LeaveLength_JS_G` function. Inside that i am setting xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange=function(). That is not executing.

My function is as follows:

```
function fun_LeaveLength_JS_G(dG1,dG2)
{
    err2=true;

    G_EmpIdFromJS=document.frmLeaveApp.txtG_EmpId.value;
    G_PL_CountJS=document.frmLeaveApp.txt_PLCount.value;

    PLAvailabe_JS= document.frmLeaveApp.PL_available.value;

    CLAvailabe_JS=document.frmLeaveApp.CL_available.value;

    LWPAvailabe_JS=document.frmLeaveApp.LWP_available.value;
    MLAvailabe_JS=document.frmLeaveApp.ML_available.value;

    COMPAvailabe_JS=document.frmLeaveApp.COMP_available.value;

    FromHomeAvailabe_JS=document.frmLeaveApp.txt4mHome_available.value;

    LeaveType_JS=document.frmLeaveApp.sltLeaveType.value;

    alert(PLAvailabe_JS+" "+ CLAvailabe_JS +" "+ LWPAvailabe_JS +" "+ MLAvailabe_JS +" "+ COMPAvailabe_JS +" "+ FromHomeAvailabe_JS + " "+ LeaveType_JS);
    if (dG1=="" || dG2=="")
    {
      return;
    }
    FromDate_G= dG1;
    ToDate_G=dG2;

    var d = new Date();

    //if(str=="")
    {   
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
          xmlhttp2=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
          xmlhttp2=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }           
        xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange=function()
        {                           
            alert("Before response from the AJAX");
          if (xmlhttp2.readyState==4 && xmlhttp2.status==200)
            {                
               document.frmLeaveApp.txtLeaveLeangth.value=xmlhttp2.responseText;    

               alert("in ajax fileError 2 is "+err2);
                alert("Ajax result is : "+xmlhttp2.responseText);
                //LeaveLength_JS=xmlhttp2.responseText();
                if(xmlhttp2.responseText==1)
                {       
                    err2=true;
                    alert("when ajax result is 1 error 2 is "+err2);

                    LeaveLength_JS=xmlhttp2.responseText();                     
                }                   
                if(xmlhttp2.responseText==0)
                {
                    err2=false;// allow to apply leave
                    alert("when ajax result is 0 error 2 is "+err2);
                }
                else
                {
                    err2=true;
                    alert("when ajax result is other then error 2 is "+err2);

                    Alert("This is developer error. Please Inform to System admin");
                }                                       
            }
        }           
        xmlhttp2.open("GET","http://localhost/MyProject/LeaveLength_Ajax.php?_Get_FromDate="+FromDate_G+"&_Get_ToDate="+ToDate_G+"&PLAvailabe_JS="+PLAvailabe_JS +"&CLAvailabe_JS="+CLAvailabe_JS +"&LWPAvailabe_JS="+LWPAvailabe_JS+"&MLAvailabe_JS="+MLAvailabe_JS+"&COMPAvailabe_JS="+COMPAvailabe_JS+"&FromHomeAvailabe_JS="+FromHomeAvailabe_JS +"&LeaveType_JS="+LeaveType_JS,true);          
        xmlhttp2.send();
    }       
    alert("At the end Error 2 is "+err2);
}
```

Where did this go wrong? Do I need to include or install any supporting software?

Comment: alert(xmlhttp2.readyState) inside the readystatechange, check if it ever reach 4

Comment: yes its working fine in Win-XP machine

Comment: i doubt web application started depending on OS ???

Comment: Yes the same code I am trying to execute in both Win 2003 and Win-XP machine. There is no issue in Win-XP but the code which is running in the Win-2003 is not working at all

Comment: Ya I have tried in both the OS.

Comment: Could any one help me to edit the Question. The code has pasted twice.

Answer (score 0):

works fine here.
you are using IE6?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the issue here has anything to do with the operating system. When you are trying this on Win2003, are you actually *at that machine* while testing it? Because you're trying to go query `localhost`, which means that you are querying a local machine and not a network address.

Try changing this line:

```
xmlhttp2.open("GET","http://localhost/...")
```

To something like this:

```
xmlhttp2.open("GET","http://<server name or IP>/...")
```

Comment: I have hosted in Both Windows 2003 and Win-XP. And trying work in the same machines. As you are telling, I am not accessing or browsing the pages from Win-2003